# Android: in my application, can I add a view on other application?

Tags: android, view, overlay, always-on-top

For example, my app is called A and other app is called B.
I want to do one of the followings:
1. click a button in A and it will trigger some event/function, so that I can have a **Button on B** when I switched from app A to app B.
2. click a button in A, and then an **always-on-top** Button will be generated and the button maintains showing when I switch to other apps or back to home screen.
Would there be a way to do such things?

Comment: means you want to go from one app to another app through button click.

Comment: @jiten no, what i mean is to show a button on other app

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open another app activity from your activity then you have to use this.

com.example is your another app package name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however, that's not what I want. The other app B isn't an activity written by me, that would be an app that is downloaded from PlayStore or somewhere.